# Bivariate Continuous Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the marginal density of $X$ and $Y$ given the
probability density function,
${f(x,y)= \lbrace3x ,\;\;0\le y\le x\le1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculating $f_X(x)$ you integrate $f(x,y)$ w.r.t $y$. The integration limits are 0 and x, because y is defined between 0 and x:

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^x 3x\ \ dy$$

For calculating $f_Y(y)$ you integrate $f(x,y)$ w.r.t $x$. The integration limits are y and 1, because x is defined between y and 1:

$$f_Y(y)=\int_y^1 3x\ \ dx$$

**Remark**

Additionally you can check, if $\int_0^1 f_X(x) \ \ dx=1$ and $\int_0^1 f_Y(y) \ \ dy=1$. If so, then $f(x,y)$ is a pdf.

Comment: @maskleon You are welcome.